# I want to cut a transparent line through my text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics-editing

Here is my text:

[image]

I simply want to cut a line/shape I make - Cut a layer from an other layer.

Comment: There are several methods you can use to accomplish this, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean by cut a line/shape. Can you perhaps create an example image where you show the result you're after?

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10305502_1736442596583502_4947318803175177746_n.jpg?oh=8f440a10a5df2c0e41bfe51d07e5f8d6&oe=56DF8DEF&__gda__=1457916504_9ca1bf0f07c847f53bd0a9d53a0583e8

Answer (score 1):

Easy: Create your line/shape, convert it to a selection, and then create an alpha mask.

You can accomplish this several ways, here's one:

1. Use the pen tool and draw a shape over your text.
2. Open the Paths tab (Top Menu: Window > Path) select the path, and then in the bottom of the tab window click on the "load path as selection" button, it looks like an ellipse marquis (circle drawn with a dashed line).
3. Top Menu: Layer > Layer Mask > Apply (Your desired mask will be inverted, don't worry, there's only one more step to fix this)
4. Invert the mask by opening the Properties Tab (Top Menu: Window > Properties), then in the *Refine* Section click the *Invert* button.

Another way to do it quickly is to select your layer, click on the "add layer mask" button in the bottom of the layers tab window (it looks like a rectangle with a circle in it) then click on the layer mask thumbnail, and "paint" the transparency in using the paint brush tool. Use black to make things invisible, White to make then visible again.

Comment: Thanks,but lost at one step..

Layer > layer mask > apply is greyed out

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10305502_1736442596583502_4947318803175177746_n.jpg?oh=8f440a10a5df2c0e41bfe51d07e5f8d6&oe=56DF8DEF&__gda__=1457916504_9ca1bf0f07c847f53bd0a9d53a0583e8

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts `Layer > Layer mask > Apply` is actually not what you want. `Apply` applies the mask to the layer. If it makes it any easier, you can think of it as something like 'mask rasterizer'. `Apply` is something that you can use when you already have a Layer mask. When you `Apply` a mask, the hidden parts of the mask are permanently removed from your layer and the mask will be removed because it's no longer needed (You can't use `Apply` on every single layer type). What you want is either `Layer > Layer mask >` ... `Reveal selection` or `Hide selection`.